# The number of multiples of $10^{44}$ that divide $10^{55}$.

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of Multiples of $10^{44}$ that divide $ 10^{55}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146701/number-of-multiples-of-1044-that-divide-1055)

I want to find out the number of multiples of $10^{44}$ that divide $10^{55}$ from the following options.

$(a)\ 11\ (b)\ 12\ (c)\ 121\ (d)\ 144$.
I don't know which option is correct and please explain the method.

Comment: This is a [duplicate of a previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/146701/5531).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any multiple of $10^{44}$ is of the form $10^{44} a$, where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. We want $10^{44} a \vert 10^{55}$. Equivalently, we want $a \vert 10^{11}$. So all you need is to count the number of divisors of $10^{11}$. Can you complete it from here?

Move your mouse over the gray area below for another hint.

> In general, if you know that prime factorization of $m$, i.e. say $m= p_1^{\alpha}p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$, then by a simple counting argument the number of divisors of $m$ is given by (why?) $$d(m) = (1+\alpha_1)(1+\alpha_2) \cdots (1+\alpha_k)$$

Move the mouse over the gray area below for the complete answer.

> Hence, all you need to get the prime decomposition of $10^{11}$. The prime decomposition of $10^{11}$ is $2^{11} \times 5^{11}$. Hence, the number of divisors of $10^{11}$ is given by $(1+11) \times (1+11) = 144$. Hence, the number of multiples of $10^{44}$ that divide $10^{55}$ is $144$.

Comment: ok! number of divisors of $10^{11}=2^{11}.5^{11}$ is $144$. I am using $\tau{(p^{\alpha})}=(\alpha +1)$.

Comment: @KunjanShah Yes. you are correct.